# AKKA: Painless Actor Error Notifications

Tags: scala, akka

### Beautiful People Lifestyle

- A component `BEAUTIFUL` is using her internal `akka.actor.Actor` to do certain things.. ( such as "acting up" for example )
- There are other `MAN` components that would really like to "interact" with the `BEAUTIFUL`
- When the `BEAUTIFUL` finds a `MAN` worthy, before "interacting" with him, she agrees to take in his phone number ( let's call it an `ErrorHandler` ), you know just to give him a call in case he left in the morning and forgot his Rolex on her bed side table
- The `BEAUTIFUL` though is "high maintenance" ( aren't they all.. ), and every time something bad happens inside the `BEAUTIFUL`'s internal Actor ( e.g. an `OmgBrokenNailException`, `UglyPurseThrowable`, etc.. ), she goes nuts, needs to stop completely and to call a `MAN` using that phone number ( e.g. `errorHandler.getOnItNowHoney( message, throwable )` )

### Beautiful People Problem

AKKA supervisors allow to register two types of FaultHandlers => `OneForOneStrategy` and `AllForOneStrategy`, where if the underlying Actor overrides preRestart/postRestart, it gets access to an actual "throwable" e.g.:

```scala
override def preRestart( reason: Throwable ) { // do with throwable... }
```

The problem is both of these strategies will try to restart the Actor(s), which is not something that I am looking for. I am looking for the Actor to call an external `ErrorHandler` with the "throwable" and stop.

If I don't use these strategies, when exception is thrown from within the Actor, a `postStop` is called on the Actor, which is cool, but it does not take in a "throwable":

```scala
override def postStop() { // no access to "throwable"... }
```

Help the `MAN` to get that `throwable`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Akka 2 you should use [DeathWatch](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/scala/fault-tolerance.html)

Comment: Viktor, we are already relying on AKKA 1.2 which is up and working. We can't switch to 2.0, not only because it is breaking, but also because it is a milestone. What would be the most elegant AKKA 1.2 way to achieve error notifications to the external processes?

Comment: External processes? Take a look at the EventHandler, you can add listeners to it and publish messages to it.

Comment: Viktor, EventHandler will do. The only caveat, seems that I need to do `EventHandler.shutdown()` in case I'd like to finish that JVM process. I read that you recommended "turn off logging and the problem will go away", but it does not, unless I force an `EventHandler.shutdown()`. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: You can try a little work-around (in 1.3-RC6) by setting the "akka.event-handlers" configuration property to a FQN of an Actor that extends EventHandler.DefaultListener and sets the self.dispatcher to a ThreadBasedDispatcher whose ThreadPoolConfig has deamonic=true

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, I think it would make sense to wrap your message processing in a try/catch block and let the actor handle sending the Throwable and stopping itself.

```
def receive = {
  case message => try { message match {
    case ... //your actual message processing goes here
  }} catch {
    case t: Throwable => {
      errorHandler ! t
      self.stop
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: would not that defeat the whole purpose of _supervising_?