# AKKA: Shutting Down EventHandler

Tags: scala, event-handling, akka

In order to notify external (to AKKA) components in case an error occurred within an Actor, we use an [ErrorHandler](http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.2/general/event-handler.html) listener per one of the SO [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746521/akka-painless-actor-error-notifications).

Some errors require a complete process / JVM stop. In which case unless we call:

```
EventHandler.shutdown()
```

It keeps the process up.

What would be a clean way to shutdown JVM process in this case? And if we do need to use `EventHandler.shutdown()`, what would be the most logical ( AKKA? ) place to invoke it from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running the Akka Microkernel it will be done for you. If you're running it using an AkkaLoader in a ServletContainer, it will be done for you. Do you have a defined application lifecycle?

Comment: Viktor, we use Spring to starts things up => a Spring Container. Although it does not seem to matter, as I just tried it via App, via ScalaTest, the process does not stop. [ add listener to the `EventHandler`, start an actor, send a message to an actor that makes the actor to throw a RuntimeException, listener gets its error, actor stops fine => JVM process is still up, unless `EventHandler.shutdown()` is called ]

Comment: Shouldn't the listener then shut down the EventHandler?

Comment: feels a bit strange to add a listener to an EventHandler: `EventHandler.addListener(errorHandlerEventListener)`, and then have that same listener to shutdown it's superset including other possible listeners. Would that be a clean way to do it in the AKKA universe?

Comment: Well, somewhere something needs to be in control of shutting down the application

Comment: ok, we can afford to do it in a listener, although the approach seems to be a bit strange. Thank you Viktor.

Comment: The problem doesn't exist in 2.0 tho :-)